# Solr spellcheck in Morfologik dictionary

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I have a problem with spellcheck in SOLR. I'm using the Morfologik dictionary.

First, when I open query url: `/solr/biurwa/select?q=dlug&indent=true`
I get some hints:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">5</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="q">dlug</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
</result>
<lst name="spellcheck">
  <lst name="suggestions">
    <lst name="dlug">
      <int name="numFound">3</int>
      <int name="startOffset">0</int>
      <int name="endOffset">4</int>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <str>dług</str>
        <str>długi</str>
        <str>druk</str>
      </arr>
    </lst>
    <lst name="collation">
      <str name="collationQuery">dług</str>
      <int name="hits">11</int>
      <lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections">
        <str name="dlug">dług</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="collation">
      <str name="collationQuery">długi</str>
      <int name="hits">14</int>
      <lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections">
        <str name="dlug">długi</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="collation">
      <str name="collationQuery">druk</str>
      <int name="hits">2</int>
      <lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections">
        <str name="dlug">druk</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

But when I use the spell url:

```
solr/spell?q=dlug&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&wt=json&indent=true
```

I get zero hints:

```
<response>    
    <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
    </result>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
      <lst name="suggestions">
        <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
      </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Can someone tell me why? Here is my schema.xml:

```
<schema name="offer" version="1.0">

 <types>
     <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK"/>
          </analyzer> 
     </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntField"/>
    <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongField"/>
    <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatField"/>
    <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoubleField"/>
    <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />
 </types>

 <fields>
   <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="barcode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="code_producer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="sku" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="true" />
   <field name="description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="available" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="active" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="price_retail" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="price_retail_old" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="price_wholesale" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="price_wholesale_old" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="price_euro" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="price_VAT" type="double" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="status_new" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="status_sale" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="status_promotion" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="status_soon" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="status_proposal" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
   <field name="id_producer" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="id_file" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="file" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false" />
   <field name="id_category" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
   <!-- must have -->
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="code" dest="text"/>
<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

</schema>
```

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this error?

Comment: @michal, @Vail: this is because morfologik dictionary doesn't have unidecoded polish words (`dług` is in dictionary, but `dlug` is not). It is possible to modify this dictionary, and recompile it. To be honest, I am actually working on documenting how I did this, right now, Be patinent :)